# Test of package A needs package B which depends on A

Tags: r, package, devtools, testthat

For a unit test in my package A I want to load package B which imports package A. The following emulates the behavior and unfortunately fails:

```
library(devtools)
load_all("./A/")
library("B")
```

Results in

```
Loading required package: B
Error: package ‘A’ required by ‘B’ could not be found
```

Is there a way to load B without it wanting to load A again, which obviously gets kind of blocked by devtools so that it's not loaded twice.

Details:

- A suggests B
- B depends on A

Comment: Have you built package `A`?

Comment: Yes. Just calling `library("B")`  as well as `library("A")` works fine.